# How do I authenticate a user with a decoupled frontend (SPA React/React-Router) and backend (node.js) with openIDConnect?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, openid-connect

The app I'm working on has frontend that serves a SPA (React/React-Router) and API backend (node.js). I'm supposed get this OpenIDConnect login implementation fully working. It was already  partially set up and "works".  My problem is my SPA doesn't know whether or not it's authenticated. I found another post where someone suggested using using React-Router `onEnter` and creating a function that just queries an endpoint to see if the user is authenticated but `onEnter` is deprecated; and the suggested replacement for that (put custom code in the `render` prop) doesn't seem to work well with any of my http request libraries because they are all async.

**The suggested React-Router replacement I found**

```
        <Route
          path="/content"
          render={(props) => {
            this.isAuthenticated() ? 
            (<ContentContainer {...props}/>):(<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />)
          }}
        />
```

How can I replace the original functionality of `onEnter` or is there a better way of handling authentication? I included the code for the backend below in case there's a better way.

**BACKEND/API that does the authentication**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", config.frontEndUrl);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({resave: 'true', saveUninitialized: 'true' , secret: 'keyboardsaff2'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    done(null, obj);
});

var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
     authorizationURL : config.authorization_url,
     tokenURL : config.token_url,
     clientID : config.client_id,
     scope: 'openid',
     response_type: 'code',
     clientSecret : config.client_secret,
     callbackURL : config.callback_url,
     skipUserProfile: true,
     issuer: config.issuer_id,
     addCACert: true,
     CACertPathList: []
     },
    (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {
        process.nextTick(() => {
            profile.accessToken = accessToken;
            profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
            done(null, profile);
        })
});

passport.use(Strategy);

app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {}));


function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/auth/sso/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    var redirectURL = req.session.originalUrl;
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect: redirectURL,
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
    })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/failure', (req, res) => {
    res.send('login failed'); 
});

app.get('/authenticate', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {   
    var claims = req.user['_json'];
    res.redirect(req.query.redirectUrl+"?id="+req.user.id.toLowerCase()+(req.query.firstName?"&firstName="+req.query.firstName:"")+(req.query.lastName?"&lastName="+req.query.lastName:"")+(req.query.companyName?"&companyName="+req.query.companyName:"")+(req.query.role?"&role="+req.query.role:""));
});
```